# openpyxl no attribution error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

### Python 3.5  openpyxl 2.4

Hi everyone, I got a simple but confusing problem here.
FYI the API doc relating to worksheet is

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html

Here is some simple code for testing.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
print (wb2.get_sheet_names())
ws = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print (type(ws))
print (ws.calculate_dimension())

list = []
for i in ws.rows:
    print ('\n')
    for cell in i:
        list.append(cell.value)
        print(str(cell.value).encode('utf-8'))
print (type(ws))
ws.get_highest_row()
```

here's what turned out eventually

```
<class 'openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
ws.get_highest_row()
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'get_highest_row'
```

I run into the problem where it says that `get_highest_row` is not an attribute.
This seems correct since this function is under class `worksheet.worksheet` (from API doc), and `ws` is `worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet` (I've no idea what that is) may inherits some functions so it can still call `dimension()`, but can someone tell me how to fix this? I want to check through one specific row or column and do some sorting with varying length of cols and rows.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I realized that I can use the ws.max_row to get the row number, but still I want to understand what cause the previous error.

Answer (score 13):

According to https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/278/get_highest_row-column-are-unreliable

In newest `openpyxl`, which has removed `get_highest_row` and `get_highest_column` method. They have been replaced by `max_row` and `max_column` property

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with openpyxl 2.3.5 and got the following

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py:350:
>   **UserWarning: Call to deprecated function or class get_highest_row (Use
>   the max_row property).**   def get_highest_row(self):

So as you are using 2.4 they probably removed it from there as it was deprecated already in 2.3.5.

EDIT: In the [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) for 2.4 this method is not mentioned any longer

Comment: You‘’re right probably, I think they need to update this on their API library website.

Comment: They have - your link in the question just points to the documentation for 2.3.5 which still includes the method as I wrote. I added the link to the doc for 2.4 to my answer which does not inlcude the method any longer.

Comment: The idea is to deprecate nearly all the `get_*` methods replacing them with more Pythonic idioms. We're following a fairly rapid deprecation strategy to keep the documentation simple but public APIs will be around for at least one release after deprecation. All deprecations are in the change notes.